# Boolean slice while keeping all of the parts

Tags: modeling

IS it possible to boolean slice two objects and keep all of the parts? I have included an image for reference. I would like to cut a hole in the red face and cut the blue extrusion in half at the intersection. Slicing seems to always delete part of the model meaning i have to copy and paste the different parts to get it to work which is very time consuming and confusing. many thanks.

[image: boolean slice]

Comment: Sorry but you **haven't** included an image for reference! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Ah yes! Updated.